# Is returning error messages form rest services on HTTP headers safe?

Tags: java, api, rest, http

I am aware that response messages should go on the response body as the HTTP status should be enough to tell the client what she has done wrong or if there is anything else wrong on the server.

But, my is there any known specific security issue if error messages are return on headers (e.g. create a new header "error" and put the error message on it)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of error message that you send.

Hope the error message is a generic message like "Invalid Input ABC"and does not provide any code level information like "Exception occured in XYZServiceImpl".

As long as the error messages are generic there is nothing to be worried about the security.

Answer (score 1):

It will not create or remove any security risks in comparison to embedding the same error messages into the body. HTTPS encrypts all response, headers including, and any descent cracker will read your headers no problem anyway.

The less you talk about your errors to the REST caller, the better. Log more on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do that - returning error messages in headers.

However, you should do something like.

```
Unauthorized access  - header HttpStatus-401 response body- your message
Invalid params       - header HttpStatus-400 response body- your message
```

and like wise

I dont think there is any issue sending message in response body or header, or it is going to make any difference.